# Marginal Cost / Optimization

Tags: derivatives, economics

You are the owner of a competitive firm. Prices of labor and capital are \$1 each. The production function is $$F(L,K)=L^{0.25}k^{0.25}$$

1. calculate how many units of K and L you need to produce 100 units of product optimally (i.e. while minimizing costs), and what is your expenditure on inputs
2. Suppose now that your (total) cost function is given by c(q)=2q
   (where q is quantity produced) and the demand function is p=14-3q.
   Calculate marginal cost,the optimal quantity produced, and profits.

For #1 I said K=L. L*K = 100 so L and K = 10/each.  Is this right?

For #2 I calculated 14-3q = 2.  q = 4.  Then marginal cost = 14-3(4) = 2.  Is this also right?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for $1.$

The cost function is $ C(K,L)=K+L$. This has to be minimized under the constraint $100=L^{0.25}\cdot K ^{0.25}$

Solving the constraint for $K$

$K ^{0.25}=\frac{100}{L^{0.25}}$

$K=\frac{100^4}{L}$

Inserting the term for K in $C(K,L)$

$C(L)=\frac{100^4}{L}+L$

Derivative w.r.t L

$\frac{dC}{dL}=-\frac{100^4}{L^2}+1=0 \qquad |+\frac{100^4}{L^2}$

$1=\frac{100^4}{L^2} \qquad |\cdot L^2$

$L^2=100^4\Rightarrow L^*=100^2=10,000$ since $L\geq 0$

Inserting the value of L into the constraint to calculate K

$100=\left(100^2 \right)^{0.25}\cdot K ^{0.25}$

The solution is $K^*=100^2=10,000$

Comment: Thank you!  Is my #2 correct?

Comment: @MarleyChatthews Not really. Firstly the marginal cost is just the derivative of $c(q)=2q$. For the second question the profit function is $\texttt{Profit}(q)=p(q)\cdot q-c(q)=14q-3q^2-2q=12q-3q^2$. The derivative (equal to 0) w.r.t q is $12-6q=0$ Solve for q.

Comment: Gotta hit the books...thanks so much for your help today.

Comment: @MarleyChatthews You´re welcome.